# Python Selenium- Export a file to attach to a website

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, tkinter

I am creating an autofill that attaches a file to a website. I am able to get the file into Tkinter, but when I try to attach the file via the website, it only opens the file dialog box so the user has to manually select the file. I want my autofill to upload the file path when I press the "attach" button on the website.

````
# Add Attachments
try:
    if any(item == 'Financial Systems' for item in ACselection[:2]):
        attach = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="catItemTop"]/div/div[3]/div/label/sp-attachment-button/span/button')))
        attach.send_keys(filePath)
except:
    pass
    ```
````

Comment: If you are trying to attach (I assume this is synonymous with "upload") a file, there should ben input with type='file' where you can upload to. You can send the keys of your file's absolute path (os.abspath() from the os module) to this input. 

The input should be in the form "//input[@type='file']"

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to upload files via send_keys, then your xpath must contain type="file", like this: //input[@type="file"]